# How to display the content without going to another page

Tags: php, mysql

I have a message box with a submit button, when I click the submit button the content in the box should be insert in the MYSQL database, but without going to another page. The message which i just entered in the message box should be displayed in the same page after the submission. What should I do?

Comment: have your form action to target itself, `<form action=<?php echo $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']; ?> method="post">`, just make sure you have an `isset($_POST)` on top of your script.

Comment: I looks like you are looking for an ajax solution. You don't want to refresh the page correct?

Comment: Actually this stays in the same page but the data is not inserted into the database.

Comment: Yes, I don't wanted to refresh the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function postData() {
var order = 'name='+$('#textBoxId').val();
$.post("Another_PHP_Page_Path.php", order,  function(response,status, xhr){
        if (status == "success") {
            alert(response);
            $('#divId').text(response);
        }
        else if (status == "error") {
            alert('Something went wrong, we are working to fix it'); 
        }                   
});
}
</script>
```

Note: name will be posted to PHP Page and after insterting into Database you can echo anything on php page or echo name, and on response this will showing back at same page. Use postData() on button onclick and button type should be button not submit.

Answer (score 4):

Use something called AJAX..

suppose this is your code :

```
<form id="myform" action="something" <!--Add this part-->onsubmit='return sendData()'<!--End of added part-->>

Enter Message <textarea name="msg" id="msg"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit" />
</form>

 <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function sendData(){
var msgVal = $("#msg").val();

$.ajax({
    data:"msg="+escape(msg),
    url: $("#myform").attr("action"),
    type: $("#myform").attr("method"),
    success:function(){
        alert( $("#msg").val() );
    }
});

return false;

}
</script>
```